# Chicken and Dumplings soaked up all the broth

Tags: chicken, broth, dumplings

My dumplings soaked up all of the broth. What can I add to my chicken and dumplings without ruining the flavor?

Comment: which dumplings? what's the recipe? what's in the broth?

Comment: Add water?  So long as you eat it all together, the flavor should still be there, just in the dumplings

Comment: Welcome! Can you [edit] to include your recipe for dumplings and broth? Without knowing what flavor you currently have, we don't know what will work with it :)

Comment: I'm sorry to be laughing, but I did the same thing years ago. Those dumplings *really* swell.

Answer (score 6):

Add more broth.  Use either water, balanced with spices, or add from a good brand.

Edit:  You could always make more broth than you need and freeze the rest.